# Could not load type 'ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated' from assembly 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Tags: c#, vb6, interop, adodb

Look, im facing aproblem, it started to give me some headache because im looking and looking and still not luck.

I have to execute a method of a DLL from C#, this DLL was created like  4 years ago in VB 6.0 and it is registered in COM. It uses ADOB.Recordset as returning type of the method that I have to execute (no source code avaialble :S)

I've been searching how to load and execute that DLL.

I was having problems first loading it, I couldn't load it with `Server.CreateObject, Assembly.Load, Assembly.LoadFrom` so I tried to add it from references of the COM and the visual Studio Imported it in the Bin Folder with the name Interops.[Name of Dll]

When Y try to use it, it gives me compile error it says:

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'SelArregloCobertura' takes '6' arguments
```

The parameters are correct, within its type and everything. Pretty sure of this

So I tried to execute it with Reflection this is the code :

```
 ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();       
        string strRamo = "70";
        string strSubramo = "01";
        string strOficina = "070";
        int iClaveSolicitud = 7118;
        string strModulo = "0";
        int iInciso = 1;

        Poliza.clsdNTCoberturaClass oClass = new Poliza.clsdNTCoberturaClass();

        MethodInfo miSelArregloCobertura = oClass.GetType().GetMethod("SelArregloCobertura");
        miSelArregloCobertura.Invoke(oClass, new object[] { "70", "01", "070", 7118, "0", 1 });
        //oClass.SelArregloCobertura(strRamo, strSubramo, strOficina, iClaveSolicitud, strModulo, iInciso);
```

(I commented up the line that gives me the compile error)
And the error is different, is not that compile error it gives me the error in the question

```
Could not load type 'ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated' from assembly 'ADODB, Version=7.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

When I go to the metadata of the dll it seems like this.

```
 [Guid("757AC98D-3800-406F-BA47-AEDAF2EBBCDB")]
    [TypeLibType(2)]
    [ClassInterface(0)]
    public class clsdNTCoberturaClass : _clsdNTCobertura, clsdNTCobertura
    {
        public clsdNTCoberturaClass();

        [DispId(1610809344)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelArregloARenovar(string dFecha1, string dFecha2, string strNumOfic, short strCveAge, string strRamo);
        [DispId(1610809347)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelArregloCobertura(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, string strNumOfic, int lCveSol, string strModulSol, int lCveInc);
        [DispId(1610809348)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelArregloCobEst(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, short intCveInc, short intAnio, int lNumRec, string strOficRecl);
        [DispId(1610809349)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelArregloCobEstim(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, short intCveInc, short intAnio, int lNumRec, string strOficRecl);
        [DispId(1610809346)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelArregloNvaCobertura(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, string strNumOfic, int lCveSol, string strModulSol, int lCveInc, short intAnio, string strOficRecl, string intnumrec);
        [DispId(1610809345)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelCobertura(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, string strCveCober);
        [DispId(1610809350)]
        public virtual ADODB._Recordset_Deprecated SelEstCobertura(string strRamo, string strSubRamo, short intAnio, string strOficRecl, int lNumRec, short intCveInc, string strCveCober);
    }
```

So I think there is a problem with the importing  step,

Anyone have an idea of how to make this works, or there is another form to load execute a method from a dll who is registered in COM?

Any help would be really apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [Breaking change in MDAC ADODB COM components in Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/3a4ce946-effa-4f77-98a6-34f11c6b5a13)

Warning: this is a looooooooong post, your browser will hang for a while.

Update: Microsoft made a decision to revert back the type library and spin off the new interfaces, see [Windows 8 Developer Preview build contains the complete fix of the ADO typelib issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues/thread/280de88a-77dd-455e-9797-b28928206e38)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will check it as accepted, but as it seems there is no solution to this problem, I had to re do the dll into c# code to make this works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Microsoft just posted a solution, hopefully this one has the least impact to developers and their customers.

Comment: thanks I saw the post, and well they at least fixed it in windows 8, lets wait if I get another project with VB 6.0 xD thanks for the reply! I saw your post like 8 hours after the post was published by Microsoft just forgotted to thanked u! xD thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/646313/ado-programs-no-longer-work-on-customer-computers-after-recompiled-on-a-windows-7-sp1-machine) has a page on this, including some workaround info.  It has to do with breaking changes to ADODB introduced in Windows 7 SP1.

One of the workarounds is detailed at this [Microsoft Support Page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589).